# CRM_Utils_Array::value how to set value to a hook_buildForm?

Tags: hooks, php, quickform

There is a  https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_buildForm manual page, but not sure I've got it right.

Say, there is a value in a custom function, which should be set as default in a form, built using  hook_buildForm (where form itself opens in a modal frame and outside civicrm/ path).

I've a suspicions **CRM_Utils_Array::value** might be used to set a custom variable somewhere (anywhere) and get it later on wherever it  might be needed;

Have an attempt to **set value outside of hook_buildForm** like this:

```
$myVeryOwnPid = CRM_Utils_Array::value('myveryownpid', $contact['contact_id_b'], $contact['contact_id_b']);
```

and **get it from inside hook_buildForm**:

```
  $myVeryOwnPid = CRM_Utils_Array::value('myveryownpid', $_GET, '0');
```

..but, of course, nothing works, just because I clearly don't understand, how it should work. As they say, CRM_Utils_Array is the most often used feature in CiviCRM, but digging inside a source code Ive realized there is no forest for the trees (at least, for me). Any advice, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found  an answer here https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Update+custom+fields+in+contributions+and+events+by+passing+variables+in+a+URL

Nothing to do with  CRM_Utils_Array though; just plain simple passing vars via an URL.